# How to wrap each child of contentchildren in their own elements in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

lets say I want to make a component that arranges all of its children. I should be able to provide the element for example:

```
<app-layout-list>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>etc</p>
</app-layout-list>
```

and inside the app-layout-list should do something like

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ng-content>
  </li>
<ul>
```

where it generates an li for each content. Is this possible using ng-content or do I need to do something more complicated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course you can! :)

And it is very simple! ([Directly to the Stackplitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9k8y5j))

Angular provides a perfect API for this kind of problems.

Basically what you want is to splitt your `<ng-content></ng-content>` in their different parts.

First of all you have to mark the portions you want to display inside the `<li>` elements via a directive. The best way to achive this is via a `Structural Directive`, because it generates a `<ng-template></ng-template>` for us, which we need later.

The `Directive` we build is very basic. It only injects the `TemplateRef` in the constructor and saves the template in a `public variable:

**list-item.directive.ts**

```js
import { Directive, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appListItem]'
})
export class ListItemDirective {

  public itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.itemTemplate = this.templateRef;
  }

}
```

With this directive we mark our html elements which we like to place inside a `<li>` element.

**app.component.ts**

```js
<app-layout-list>
  <p *appListItem>foo</p>
  <p *appListItem>bar</p>
  <p *appListItem>etc</p>
</app-layout-list>
```

Inside `LayoutListComponent` we get hold of the projected elements via `@ContentChildren(ListItemDirective) listItems`

**layout-list.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout-list',
  templateUrl: './layout-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout-list.component.css']
})
export class LayoutListComponent {
  @ContentChildren(ListItemDirective) listItems: QueryList<ListItemDirective>;
}
```

Finally inside the `Component template` we are iterating through the `listItems` and placing the `TemplateReference` of every item inside a `ngTemplateOutlet`

**layout-list.component.html**

```js
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listItems">
    <li>
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.itemTemplate"></ng-container>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

**DEMO:** [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9k8y5j)

Comment: The Stackbltiz Demo is not available

Comment: in layout-list.component.html `item.listTemplate` should be `item.itemTemplate`,
but your answer was a great help for me, thanks

Comment: @SplitterAlex - StackBlitz demo is not available, again

Comment: @GeoffJames - StackBlitz Demo is working again. I also added a link to the source on Github.

Comment: Now try to transclude `<p *appListItem>foo</p>` with *ngFor

Comment: unfortunately this no longer works with angular 14.

Comment: @Robin That's interesting! I will have a look on that and I will update my answer as soon as I have time.

Comment: @Robin I updated the Demo to the latest version of angular 14 and it works without any changes in the code base. What excatlcy is not working for you?

Comment: @SplitterAlex Hi! Sorry for the late response. I just failed by not importing the directive in the storybook module^^ But one more question: it looks like you can't create a host binding in the directive because you only pass the template ref, correct? I would like to pass a css class into the items on my <ul>